# ¿Cómo puedo quedarme con aquellas columnas con fechas iguales, manteniendo la hora de cada una en R?

Tags: r, rstudio

Les escribo para ver si me pueden aconsejar. Dispongo de los siguientes datos:

```
id      usuario      fecha_hora
2         1          20/11/2010 08:55
2         1          20/11/2010 09:12
3         4          21/11/2010 10:08
2         2          22/11/2010 11:26 
2         2          22/11/2010 11:32
7         1          22/11/2010 12:40
2         3          25/11/2010 10:10
2         3          25/11/2010 10:35
3         4          26/11/2010 13:16
```

Lo que me gustaría es **poder quedarme tan sólo con aquellas filas en que la fecha sea igual**, teniendo en cuenta más columnas con más fechas, este es sólo un ejemplo. Es decir, me gustaría que quedase así:

```
id      usuario      fecha_hora
2         1          20/11/2010 08:55
2         1          20/11/2010 09:12
2         2          22/11/2010 11:26 
2         2          22/11/2010 11:32
7         1          22/11/2010 12:40
2         3          25/11/2010 10:10
2         3          25/11/2010 10:35
```

**Que se eliminasen las fechas del día 21/11 y 26/11 por ser diferentes o en caso contrario, que sólo me seleccione aquellas fechas iguales (20/11, 22/11 y 25/11).**

He intentado lo siguiente, primer hice *extract*, para probar si separando día y hora me podría salir:

```
df<-extract(df,fecha_hora, into = c("Fecha","Hora"), "(.*)\\s(\\S+)")
```

Y posteriormente, los he *agrupado* por Fecha.

```
nueva_fecha<-df %>%                        
  group_by(Fecha) %>%       
  tally()
```

Con esto, consigo que me diga, las fechas distintas que hay y las agrupa, por ejemplo:

```
20/11/2010  2
21/11/2010  1
22/11/2010  3
25/11/2010  2
26/11/2010  1
```

Pero claro, al separarlo, no me tiene en cuenta la hora, y al intentar hacerlo todo junto, agrupar la variable fecha_hora, no me ha funcionado y me da que sólo hay un resultado de cada, porque te cuenta las horas.

También probé con la función *distinct*:

```
df%>%
  distinct(df$fecha_hora)
```

Pero no me salieron los resultados esperados… Y lo que quiero conseguir es **quedarme con el conjunto de fecha_hora, sin tener que separarlo y eliminar los únicos**.

Cualquier duda o aclaración díganmelo.

Espero que puedan ayudarme. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es saber que fechas (sin la hora) tienen una sola fila, para terminar quitando las mismas. Con R base puedes usar `aggregate` para agrupar y contar las filas, luego la selección de las mismas es trivial

```
fechas <- aggregate( id ~ format(df$fecha_hora, "%d/%m/%Y"), df, length)
colnames(fechas) <- c('fecha', 'filas')
# Nos quedamos solo con las fecha con más de una fila
fechas <- fechas[fechas$filas> 1, ]
```

Finalmente seleccionamos las filas cuya fecha es alguna de las válidas:

```
df[format(df$fecha_hora, "%d/%m/%Y") %in% fechas$fecha, ]
```

Por otro lado, con `dplyr` puedes hacer algo parecido:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  add_count(fecha=format(fecha_hora, "%d/%m/%Y")) %>% 
  filter(n > 1)
```

Comment: Hola Patricio, le agradezco mucho su respuesta. 

Probé con dplyr, pero me salió algo que no entiendo. Se me eliminaron todas aquellas n<1, hasta aquí perfecto, porque es lo que quería, pero me apareció una nueva columna nn, donde en alguna ocasión, me marca el valor 2 a fechas, en que tan sólo hay 1. 

Ejemplo:
id  usuario     fecha_hora            n          fecha            nn
2 1 20/11/2010 08:55 2 20/11/2010 2
1 2 20/11/2010 09:12 6 20/11/2010 2
4 6 21/11/2010 10:08 2 21/11/2020 1
8 10 09/12/2010 21:17 3 09/12/2010 2
3 12 22/12/2010 20:57 4 22/12/2010 2

Comment: Como se ve en el ejemplo, tanto el 09/12/2010 como el 22/12/2010, son un solo registro de fecha, pero se marca como si hubiesen 2 y sucede algo similar con nn=3, 4… Algunos valores los marca bien, pero otros no.
Claro, en este caso podría eliminar las nn<1, pero aquellas fechas en que en nn=2, pero sólo hay una fecha, no me las eliminaría, y me interesaría quitarlas. ¿Qué cree que ha sucedido? Gracias. Quedo atento

Comment: Imposible saberlo sin ver los datos originales, Si contó dos ocurrencias debería haber dos filas, con esas fechas. ¿Con las dos soluciones pasa lo mismo?

Comment: Hola Patricio, disculpe, fue un error de principiante, ya está solucionado, me salía así porque estaba usando la BBDD editada con aquellos registros de interés, con la BBDD original y al solaparse, no se mostraba la fecha visualmente, pero si estaba internamente y por este motivo, me contaba 2, pero se mostraba sólamente 1. Gracias. 

La primera solución con aggregate, no me la muestra, porque me da el error de que el objeto no es una matriz. 

Me gustaría hacerle una pregunta relacionada, pero en función del usuario ahora.

Comment: ¿sería posible, una vez eliminadas las fechas individuales en toda la BBDD, hacer lo mismo, pero para un usuario concreto? Es decir, por ejemplo, si del usuario 1, tengo dos fechas iguales (20/11/2010) y una no (22/11/2010), para eliminar esa fecha que no es igual, ¿podría hacer algo similar que lo anterior? gracias